# Missing all my Iphoto pictures

Tags: iphoto

I have a Apple Macintosh running OSX 10.6.8. I have used iphoto since I bought my computer. I can't find my pictures - this happened once before and all I did was a "search" but that isn't working this time. What can I do to recover these images, and what locations and what tools should I be looking at to recover these images?

Answer (score 0):

Your iPhoto Library, which contains photos stored in iPhoto, is located in your Pictures folder. If you are using a newer version of iPhoto, you will need to right-click on the iPhoto Library and select Show Package Contents to view the files.

If you have trouble finding it, this [guide on moving the iPhoto library](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1229?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) also has instructions on finding it.